# How to avoid saveOrUpdate on all the columns hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi i have a class login:

```
public class Login {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int userId;

@Column(name = "user_name", nullable=false )
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password", nullable=false )
private String password;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = " user_id", 
referencedColumnName = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
referencedColumnName = "song_id"))
private List<Song> songs;
}
```

When I have to add songs to it, I  create a Login object and set the List songs,username,password and userId and say session.saveOrUpdate(login).I want only the user_id and song_id to be mapped in the ,mapping table(user_songs_mapping), But what is happening is, every time the password,username are getting updated. How can I avoid this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate does exactly what you tell it to do: you ask it to update a Login, this Login's userName and password are null, so it updates the Login and sets userName and password to null. It can't guess that you actually want to update songs of an existing Login object,  unless you tell it to do that:

```
Login existingLogin = (Login) session.get(Login.class, userId);
existingLogin.addSong(song);
```

That code does what you want to do: add a Song to an existing Login object, which already has a userId, a userName and a password, which should stay as they are.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have another problem now.Everytime I say save  (not save or update),in user_songs_mapping table its deleting the old entries where the userId matches and adding the new one. I don't want old entries to be deleted. In this way, a user can have only one song in his account which is not what I want.

Comment: Hey. I think I found out what was happening.I was doing login.setSongs() instead of login.addSong() .

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is the normal behavior of saveOrUpdate, and can not be changed easily.

What you should should ideally do is;

1. Get Login by userId
2. Change only the Songs list
3. Call saveOrUpdate

Comment: The third step is useless. All changes made to managed entities are transparently made persistent at the end of the transaction (or before).